# Signature errors when using classes with Numba

Tags: python, numba

**Edit**: It seems like the problem is actually nothing to do with the fact that the classes change. I can't seem to get *any* classes to work with Numba. Running (as an example) the code [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/numba-users/-k8Tm6oy7v0) produces errors related to signatures as well:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    class test_base_class_numba(object):
  File "numba_test.py", line 8, in test_base_class_numba
    @numba.void()
TypeError: 'Signature' object is not callable
```

---

I have a class in Python that changes to a second type of class depending on some of the initial conditions. When I try to compile this class with Numba, I get a cryptic error. This is best illustrated with an example:

```
import numba

@numba.jit
class First():
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.some_inherited_property = 1

        if test:
            self.__class__ = SecondA
        else:
            self.__class__ = SecondB

class SecondA(First):
    def some_func_a():
        print "I am class SecondA"

class SecondB(First):
    def some_func_b():
        print "I am class SecondB"

thing = First(False)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    @numba.jit
  File ".../numba/decorators.py", line 155, in jit
    targetoptions=options)
  File ".../numba/dispatcher.py", line 262, in __init__
    pysig = utils.pysignature(py_func)
  File ".../funcsigs/__init__.py", line 176, in signature
    raise ValueError('callable {0!r} is not supported by signature'.format(obj))
ValueError: callable <class __main__.First at 0x7f37696fb4c8> is not supported by signature
```

Specifying (what I think is) the signature with something like `@numba.jit("numba.void(numba.bool)")` at line 3 does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of numba do not have support for jit'ing classes. This was possible in older versions, but was removed due to poor performance in one of the later refactorings. See [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!searchin/numba-users/class$20support$20siu/numba-users/YqflWZ2XSBI/GBEzARDbOx8J).

The next release of Numba (0.20.1) should re-introduce support for them. See [discussion on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/numba-users/8SMvZfhVJkc).

Comment: Ah, I see. I couldn't find mention of that anywhere in the release notes, documentation or on Google. I'll wait until the next release, I suppose. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is a bit outdated now. Since [version 0.23.0](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.25.0/release-notes.html#version-0-23-0) numba has proper [class support](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jitclass.html) again, using the `jitclass` decorator.